# Flow typing of styled component props doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, types, flowtype, styled-components

I have this styled component:

```
type Props = {
  iconAlign: string,
};

const IconWrapper: ComponentType<Props> = styled.View`
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  ${({ iconAlign }: Props) =>
    iconAlign === 'left' ? 'left: -35px;' : 'right: -35px;'}
`;
```

And call it this way:

```
<IconWrapper iconAlign="left">
```

but Flow gives me the following error:

`Cannot call styled.View because property iconAlign is missing in object type [1] in the first argument of array element.`

```
"flow-bin": "0.96.0",
"styled-components": "^4.2.0",
libdef: styled-components_v4.x.x (satisfies styled-components@4.2.0)
```

Comment: When you called `IconWrapper` you should not pass prop `iconAlign` and it is mandatory ? you can write `ComponentType<{ iconAlign?: string }>`, so prop `iconAlign` could be undefined, or set a defaultProps for `iconAlign`.

Comment: @Deve I am passing iconAlign to my component.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like custom properties on a builtin component is not currently supported for a few reasons but namely Flow's still developing support for tagged template literals. The discussion at https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/pull/2933 is quite useful for understanding why your example won't work currently and the steps being taken to make it possible.