# property top is missing in object type [1] in the first argument of array element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, styled-components

I am using flow for static type checking. I have a component called `OverlaySpinner` which accepts props like `top, left, loading and backgroundColor`. The type of top and left is number and i have also provided the defaultProps for them. However, I get an error `property top is missing in object type [1] in the first argument of array element`.

This is the code

```
import {Wrapper, Spinner} from './styled'

const OverlaySpinner = ({
  left,
  top,
  backgroundColor,
  loading,
}: {
  left?: number,
  top?: number,
  backgroundColor?: string,
  loading: boolean,
}) => {
  if (!loading) return null

  return (
    <Wrapper left={left} top={top} backgroundColor={backgroundColor}>
      <Spinner />
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

OverlaySpinner.defaultProps = {
  left           : 0,
  top            : 0,
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
}
export default OverlaySpinner


styled.js

import styled, {type ReactComponentStyled} from 'styled-components'

type WrapperPropTypes = {
  left: number,
  top: number,
  backgroundColor: string,
}

export const Wrapper: ReactComponentStyled<WrapperPropTypes> = styled.div`
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  top: ${({top}) => top}px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: ${({left}) => left}px;
  right: 0;
  background: ${({backgroundColor}) => backgroundColor};
`
```

Screenshot of issue

[image]

Comment: Should the defaultProps have the values as strings and not as numbers?

Comment: sorry i did not get you.

Comment: Your `defaultProps` say `top: 0` which means top is a number 0. You say in the object definition that top should be a string. So defining it as a string (`top: “0”`) may help?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I apologize, I copied my code from another tab. I was trying different way to figure out the issue. I have updated my code. I checked in the console and the typeof top and typeof left gives me number but flow still throws an error.

Comment: The error seems to be in the flow-typed definitions of styled components but could you remove the optional from the types in the `OverlaySpinner` as suggested by the docs on React components: https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/#toc-using-default-props
Sometimes the error seems to be somewhere else than it actually is. If we ruled that out we could dig into the mentioned flow types of styled components.

Comment: if i remove the optional then i get `property top is missing in object type [1] in the first
   argument of array element.` which is the same issue. I could not even create a sandbox as i need to run the script ./node_moduels/.bin/flow-typed install and i have no idea on how i do this in codesandbox.

Comment: I think this might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55689609/flow-typing-of-styled-component-props-doesnt-work. I've tried dealing with `styled-components` and Flow before and it usually doesn't go too well. I'll try again with your specific example, but I'm guessing you're running into the same limitations.